# (UNITY) Is it possible to change layout based on Screen.Orientation without duplicating all of the gameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mobile app that can be used in portrait or landscape, and obviously the amount of screen real estate changes, so I need to rearrange the enable/disable certain objects to be able to fit into the screen. I'd like to find the most elegant way to create different 'layouts' per se, so that when the user changes orientation, certain elements move, and certain disappear/appear based on which way they're looking.

Right now it seems the only option is to duplicate the canvases, and then just enable/disable them in an if/else, but then I'd have to duplicate *all* of my mediator logic as well, and that would be a HUGE undertaking, and then any time I changed anything I'd have to do it to each one separately. That's not an ideal solution for me.

Any ideas, guys? I have no clue what to ask specifically to get to where I need to go from a resource standpoint. Thanks!

Comment: Why not give it an animator, and when you detect the change in the orientation set the animator to load the different lay or "Move" things super fast.

Comment: The reason I'm not keen on that is I have DOTween installed, and the 'animation' of the canvases (they still have to overlay each other when different canvases are selected etc) is handled through DOTween. If I have animator, I'd have to hard-code values in, and it wouldn't work on different resolutions, correct?

Comment: TBH, I am not sure I do not use DOTween never had a need for it.  Most of the functionality that it adds I can do in Unity without it.

Comment: It's just easy to init and then start using. Either way, I adjust positions outside of keyframes.